# Autodesk Platform Services - Data Management - Upload first version error

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

Similar issue to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50109167/autodesk-forge-api-uploading-file-fails)
However, the solution does not resolve my issue.
I'm following the step-by-step instructions listed [here](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/) and everything is working well until I get to step 7 (Create first version of the uploaded file).  I'm not sure that I need to perform this step for a successful upload because it is not listed anywhere [here](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/direct-s3-net-samples). Since I'm not seeing my file appear in my folder, I'm thinking that the first version step must be necessary.

This is the request body that I'm using:

```
string requestBody = @"
        {
            ""jsonapi"": { ""version"": ""1.0"" },
            ""data"": {
                ""type"": ""items"",
                ""attributes"": {
                    ""displayName"": """ + fileName + @""",
                    ""extension"": {
                        ""type"": ""items:autodesk.bim360:File"",
                        ""version"": ""1.0""
                    }
                },
                ""relationships"": {
                    ""tip"": {
                        ""data"": {
                            ""type"": ""versions"", 
                            ""id"": ""1""
                        }
                    },
                    ""parent"": {
                        ""data"": {
                            ""type"": ""folders"",
                            ""id"": """ + folderId + @"""
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            ""included"": [
                {
                    ""type"": ""versions"",
                    ""id"": ""1"",
                    ""attributes"": {
                        ""name"": """ + fileName + @""",
                        ""extension"": {
                            ""type"": ""versions:autodesk.bim360:File"",
                            ""version"": ""1.0""
                        }
                    },
                    ""relationships"": {
                        ""storage"": {
                            ""data"": {
                                ""type"": ""objects"",
                                ""id"": """ + objectId + @"""
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }";
```

which translates to :

```
    {
        "jsonapi": { "version": "1.0" },
        "data": {
            "type": "items",
            "attributes": {
                "displayName": "ACCUploadTest8.log",
                "extension": {
                    "type": "items:autodesk.bim360:File",
                    "version": "1.0"
                }
            },
            "relationships": {
                "tip": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "versions", 
                        "id": "1"
                    }
                },
                "parent": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "folders",
                        "id": "urn:Aadsk.wipprod:Afs.folder:Aco.CdqHiUXsTUaXBnE6Iwxb8g"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "included": [
            {
                "type": "versions",
                "id": "1",
                "attributes": {
                    "name": "ACCUploadTest8.log",
                    "extension": {
                        "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:File",
                        "version": "1.0"
                    }
                },
                "relationships": {
                    "storage": {
                        "data": {
                            "type": "objects",
                            "id": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/b1333e7c-39ae-41e4-a94e-e0c3c3c87c58.log"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

This is the response that I'm receiving:

```
{"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"},"errors":[{"id":"129d054e-6da7-4bbc-a04d-e220e7043466","status":"400","code":"BAD_INPUT","title":"One or more input values in the request were bad","detail":"Urn is not in the proper format."}]}
```

Comment: Could you please also provide the value of requestBody (i.e. the actual string that you are sending to our endpoint), not just the code that generates it?

Comment: I edited my post to include the actual string of the request body. Is creating the first version even required to post a file?  There will not be any more versions of the file posted. I'm getting successful responses all the way up to that point, but the file never appears in the folder on ACC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly mistake. It turns out that I did not properly decode my folder id url.
HttpUtility.UrlDecode()